# Why console is lagging like anything in Spring Tool Suite (STS) 4.13.0.RELEASE in Windows 10?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Check this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUdfu.jpg).
I don't know why the console is lagging like anything. I have freshly installed STS multiple times yet it's the same.

#### My PC Config:

**OS:** Windows 10 Build 19044.1466, 64-bit
**RAM:** 12GB
**Processor:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
**L3 Cache:** 3 MB

I even have increased the heap memory size from 256m to 1024m (can be seen in the console's bottom bar in the *gif*, the link shared above).

Is anyone facing the same error?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be this issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/689

The workaround would be to uninstall the ANSI Console plugin. You can do that via the About dialog, then click on installation details, select the "Ansi Console" extension and "Uninstall...".

Comment: Uninstalled it but the issue still remains the same 

Comment: Do you see the same issue in an plain Eclipse 2021-12 installation?

Comment: No, it's fine in Eclipse!

Comment: Lets continue the investigation on the mentioned GitHub issue then